# Access method parameter inside a before_filter in UserMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have several methods in `UserMailer` that are passed `user` as argument. I want to be able to access `user` in a before_filter. I guess I could access the variable converting it to an instance variable and calling a private method afterwards. Something like this:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  def welcome(user)
    @user = user
    mail(to: ...)
  end

end
```

But it feels wrong having to do it in all methods.

Is there a better way to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: If you want to access, currently logged in user, `current_user` method can help you, if you are using devise, else a method which you have to get logged in user in your authentication mechanism.

Comment: Raj, this is not the way to go as the user is kept in the session and the session should be decoupled from ActionMailer

Comment: There is no way to determine the user in a before filter?  If that before filter comes before the others then you will be fine. -> { @user = User.find(params[:user_id])} ?